# Close duplicate 32 or 64 bit application

Tags: autohotkey, 32bit-64bit

I've released a small application to a couple of my friends. Some of them needed a 32-bit version. If you have a 64-bit OS you can run both applications 64 and 32bit. This would create a duplicate.

*The question that comes to my mind is, can I prevent the same application from running twice?*

**--- Solution approach ---**

I have tried working with [WinExist](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm) creating a If-Statement at the very beginning and checking whether or not `ahk_exe MyApplicationName.exe` exists. This functions fails to succeed whenever the user changes the file name however.

I have also tried creating a `.txt` file inside the `Temp` folder, leaving behind the currents application Unique-ID so I could close the duplicate. This does not seem to be sufficient for me however, as this method allows the user to alter the ID and bypass it.

**--- Final words ---**

Any other ideas on how one could prevent the user from running both versions at the same time?

Comment: Is this application a  compiled AHK script?

Comment: I compile it with ahk2exe also using mpress.

Comment: Did you try [`#SingleInstance ignore`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_SingleInstance.htm)?

Comment: I have #SingleInstance Force. The answer from @user3419297 solved my problem though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the auto-execute section of the 32-bit version:

```
If (A_Is64bitOS)
    ExitApp
```